# Custom string representation of a custom typed collection

Tags: java, string, collections

If I need a custom string representation of a custom typed collection, which is the best option-subclass the collection and override the toString(), or just create a utility method that takes the custom typed collection and returns the custom string? Is there another option?

Comment: If you could tell, what is that for please, because otherwise, I think the best option is making a subclass of the collection and override toString() like you say...

Comment: you say custom collection, which seems to imply you have already subclassed or implemented a collection interface, so `toString()` would be the best option.

Answer (score 2):

I would tend to create a utility method. A few reasons:

- Logically, your custom string representation is something that you are layering on top of the original class: it is not part of the original class. So it doesn't belong inside the definition of the original class.
- Creating a subclass is probably overkill just to override one method
- Creating a custom subclass makes it impossible to work with objects that override the original class for a different reason. You inheritance heirarchy can quickly become unmanageable if you use inheritance for things like this. Always prefer composition to inheritance!
- You may want to continue to use the original `toString()` for some reasons: perhaps you need both string representations, or some other library depends on the original `toString()` behaviour. In which case overriding it will cause problems.....

Within the "utility method" option your have another choice:

- Create a simple static utility method. Simple, quick, this should probably be your first choice.
- Create a "Formatter" object with a method like `formatter.formatAsString(targetObject)`. This can be useful if you have some formatting options that you can store in the formatter.

Comment: +1 - Always prefer composition to inheritance

Answer (score 0):

The Java object's http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html
 `toString` method is intended to provide a string representation for the object. So overriding the `toString` sounds logical.